# Python 2.4.3 Converting String to Bits and Vice-versa

Tags: python

How can i convert Hex Digits to Binary and then perform "OR" operation in Python 2.4.3 ?

Example-

```
a= '1000'
b= '2000'

//Now convert both numbers a and b to binary form
//a_inbinary= '0001000000000000'
//b_inbinary= '0010000000000000'

c= a_inbinary | b_inbinary // or of a and b

//c would be result example - 0011000000000000

result=3000 //c in hex
```

Can someone please tell me that how i can convert two numbers to binary form and then result into hexadecimal form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to convert them to binary form to do the bitwise operations, but decimal integers should be fine. You can convert the numbers to base 10 by specifying the actual base, in which the numbers are represented, as the second parameter to `int` function. Finally, the result which is in decimal form can be converted back to hexa decimal using, `hex` function.

```
a= '1000'
b= '2000'
print hex(int(a, 16) | int(b, 16))
```

**Output**

```
0x3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first two strings are 0x1000 and 0x2000 there is no need to convert to a binary string, just use the bitwise or operator `|`

```
a='1000'
b='2000'
a=int(a,16)
b=int(b,16)
hex(a|b)
```